# Deploying only 3rd party jars into artifactory

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

i have a pom.xml file, here some 3rd party jars dependency is there and some project related jar is there.I need to deploy only 3rd party jars into artifactory not all the jars.For that what is the pom structure....

Answer (score 0):

Try to build the project (with `settings.xml` point to Artifactory [according to the docs](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Artifacts+Resolution)). Maven will resolve all  the dependencies and will cache them in Artifactory.